# ¿Como podria reutilizar mi tabla foto en base de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

tengo una tabla tema, la cual puede tener varias fotos,y también tengo mi tabla publicación y también puede tener fotos,como podría reutilizar mi tabla fotos,para usarla en la tabla publicación?.gracias de antemano
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Crea otra tabla para la relación entre publicación y foto, de forma que tengas que relacionar la publicación con una foto ya existente.